# Marker issue with the google tutorial "Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps"

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make a database of locations to fill out a FAFSA for my non profit and put them up on a google map with a custom marker image but cant seem to get the markers to show up.

here is the php to create the xml:

```
<?php
require("mapdbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("Localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());}

$query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("date", $row['date']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("cord", $row['cord']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("cord_info", $row['cord_info']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

here is the java script:

```
 function load() {
 var location_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/FAFSA_Logo_icon.png');   
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.105305, -106.628014),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  }

downloadUrl("mapmysql.php", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<b> Cordinator </b>" + cord +    cord_info;
var icon =  location_icon;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
  icon: icon      
});
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
     new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
     new XMLHttpRequest;

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
     callback(request, request.status);
   }
 };

 request.open('GET', url, true);
 request.send(null);
}
```

I can't figure out why they markers aren't showing up. the file is located in that images folder but, there are to many places that this could be going wrong for me to effectively troubleshoot with my current knowledge. I pretty much copied and pasted the code from the google example except for adding some fields to pull from the xml and added a custom icon image.

Any ideas on how to get these markers to show up? the map shows up with the center and zoom I have selected but not the markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may see a few problems (I'll get to them in a minute), but first I'm going to try to offer some more general debugging advice -

Testing someone's code which relies on a server-side code is pretty tricky, even if it's your own. The first thing I would do in a case like this is create a generic xml file to parse, and  include it in the page. Then, hopefully you can tell if the bug is occurring in the map rendering portion of the code if something goes wrong. If it works, then you can narrow the bug down to being either on the server, or in the code you're using to get it from the server.

Next, I would try to put the xml file on the server as-is, and see if the client-side file download is working. I suspect this is where you'd notice at least one error. Right now, your map rendering depends on two separate steps: the "load" function, which initializes the map; and a call to the "downloadURL" function, which you're relying on to get the marker data.

The problem is in how you structured the calls. The "map" variable you created in "load" is local to "load" itself; you cannot access it outside of it. There are two ways you can fix this particular problem: you can turn map into a global variable, or add all code that manipulates map within "load". If you wish to do the former, you just do this:

```
var map;
function load() {
  var location_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/FAFSA_Logo_icon.png');
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.105305, -106.628014),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
```

This adds "map" to the global scope, allowing it to be used outside of "load".

However, there's still a problem with doing this as-is: this won't guarantee that "load" has initialized the map by the time "downloadURL" starts manipulating it. There's a chance that it will attempt to add "markers" to "map" before "load" has had a chance to create map in the first place. Fortunately, this can be solved by putting the "downloadURL" call within "load", like so:

```
function load() {
  var location_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/FAFSA_Logo_icon.png');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.105305, -106.628014),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("mapmysql.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<b> Cordinator </b>" + cord + cord_info;
      var icon = location_icon;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}
```

This ensures that markers will only be added to the map after the map has been created, and that they'll have access to map in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Bubbles! initializing "map" outside of "load", then putting "downloadUrl" inside of "load" seemed to solve the issue. I would leave a comment on the tutorial about this but I don't think there was a way to do that.

I also initialized "location_icon" outside of everything just to be on the safe side.

Comment: You're welcome! Do you have a link to the tutorial? I'm kinda curious.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 is the link to their tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the javascript console for errors
2. Check the xml. Point your browser at it, see if it thinks it is valid.
3. Use a debugger (or just add an alert) in your map where it parses the marker xml, check that the length of the markers variable that is being processed by this for loop is correct:

   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

One of the above should point to the issue.  If not, post a link to your live map and someone can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip. I used the console on chrome to find out I had several errors with variables. I hadn't thought of that before your comment.